# ip addresses not meeting the IP addressing requirements of our company's network

Tags: router, ip, network-access

Here is the situation: 
 In my company we only use static IP addresses, the address of the router interface on which every machine is connected is 192.168.0.1/16.
Our router support the DPI (Deep Packet Inspection) feature and shows us the ip addresses of all machines connected as well as their traffic. What is confusing me is i have found ip addresses starting by 81.x.x.x and 116.x.x.x on our LAN.
**How in the world is this possible?? Since the address of the interface LAN is 192.168.0.1/16, i should only see ip addresses looking like this 192.168.x.x, shouldn't i?** 
The first thing i have noted is those weird ip addresses have a few Kbytes traffic. That's why i have tried to capture packets with Wireshark on every active interface of the router (to gather any information about them). And filtering the display with those addresses, i have found no packets matching them.
 Moreover a geolocalisation (using [this webtool](https://www.iplocation.net)) of one of the ip address indicates it comes from China (we are located in Africa). Could have our network been hacked? And if so, how could i identify explicitly the hacking and prevent it from happening again?

Comment: You do mean 192.168.0.1/16, with an 8, don't you?

Comment: Does your router show you the MAC addresses associated with the anomalous IPs?

Comment: @Law29. You are right. My mistake, i meant 192.168.0.0/16

Comment: @law29. The DPI feature doesn't show the MAC address therefore i took a glance at the arp tables of the router but i can't find those weird ip addresses.

Comment: What kind of router /firewall do you have?

Comment: Right, the router ARP tables would probably not show them since there would not normally be any packets sent **to** those addresses at layer 2.

Comment: @Ron Truk. We have a EdgeMAX router

Comment: First thought: Spoofing.

Comment: STUN, TURN and ICE are methods that assume certain behavior from the NAT/firewall and do not work in all scenarios. The
control is removed from the firewall which has to be sufficiently opened to allow users to create the pinholes needed to let the
communication through.  https://www.ingate.com/files/Solving_Firewall-NAT_Traversal.pdf

Comment: @Ricky Beam. How a spoofing attack (SA) would make those weird ip address appear on the network since SA is based on (and tell me if i am wrong) using legit ip addresses to get data destined for the spoofed ip address?

Comment: @Ron Royston. I have read a bit about those methods and the NAT traversal problem. If those methods failed the peer-to-peer communication would end. Sio i don't understand how this is related to my problem about seeing weird IP addresses on my network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to drop and log any outgoing packets that do not have a valid source address (192.168.0.0/16 in your case). Depending on your equipment, for that log to contain the MAC you may need to put it on your internal interface or turn on verbose logging or something else (see Ron Trunk's comment asking you for router/firewall make and model)

If you get hits, then you have a MAC, and you can look for that MAC on your switches.

Comment: Actually since each and every ip address is manually created so that its bandwidth can be set, **there is already a firewall rule allowing only outgoing traffic for those static ip addresses we have created**. However i am going to check if we can log outgoing traffic not corresponding to a valid ip